# How to show image in datagridview as thumbnail

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `windows application form` and i need to show the image `thumbnails` 
in `datagridview`.

The images are stored as binary data in SQL Server 2005.

Is there any method to show image's `thumbnails` without storing image as file on disc.

Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a datagridviewimage column set  width of the column and set data-source after that loop through each row and set  row height.

## Example

```
dgvEmpInfo.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

       foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dgvEmpInfo.Rows)
       {
           dgvRow.Height = 100;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.I'll assume you have the images stored in a byte array:

```
byte[] bArray = GetRawImageBytes();

// Get an image object from the byte-array
Image ddbImage;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bArray, 0, bArray.Length))
{
    ms.Write(bArray, 0, bArray.Length);
    ddbImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
}

// Create a 100x100 thumbnail from the image
var ThumbnailSize = new Size(100, 100);
var thumb = ddbImage.GetThumbnailImage(
            ThumbnailSize.Height, 
            ThumbnailSize.Width, 
            null, IntPtr.Zero);

// Create an image column for the datagridview
var imgColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn
{
    HeaderText = "Image", 
    Name = "img"
};

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgColumn);

// Add the first row, using this image
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = thumb;

// lets set the gridview-height to the thumbnail height
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Height = ThumbnailSize.Height;
}
```

**Edit:** For convenient cut & paste code for testing, here is a dummy function that will return a byte-array of an image stored on disk:

```
private byte[] GetRawImageBytes()
{
    var img = Image.FromFile(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGE);
    byte[] bArray;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        bArray = ms.GetBuffer();
    }
    return bArray;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's working but.I got a simple solution for that.Just add a datagridviewimage column and set width of the column.and after setting datasource loop through each datagridview row and set height.That's it.